# XMLHttpRequest responseXML is null on firefox 10

Tags: post, firefox-addon, xmlhttprequest

I have XMLHttpRequest inside firefox addon which like this :

```
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open("POST", baseUrl + "check.php?uid=" + username, true);
httpRequest.responseType = "document";
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");      
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", dataString.length);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
httpRequest.onload = infoReceived;
httpRequest.send(dataString);
```

I works just fine on recent version of firefox (14.0.1).

However, on Firefox ESR 10, httpRequest.responseXML is **null** inside handler procedure (infoReceived)

Any hint, please?

I check MDN docs but there is no note about incompatibility in ESR 10 version.

Comment: What is the content type of the response?

Comment: So what did you expect? `XMLHttpRequest` only parses XML...

Comment: @WladimirPalant you did not get what I want to achieve.I want to parse foreign HTML as DOM.Now I can.Of course with XMLHttpRequest .By the way you can use it for plain text, json, etc ... (not just XML)

Comment: Sure you can - but the `responseXML` property is reserved for XML. Everything else affects the newer `response` property only. Btw, you didn't *tell* what you are trying to achieve until I asked you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figure it out.

Before (inside handler function):

```
var response = httpRequest.responseXML;
```

After (inside handler function):

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var response = parser.parseFromString(httpRequest.responseText, "text/html");
```

Before (main function) :

```
httpRequest.responseType = "document";
```

After (main function) :

```
//httpRequest.responseType = "document";
```

I also found correct info inside [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest):

[image]